# How to avoid an item's layout changes from repeating in a RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

In my `RecyclerViewAdapter`; when changes made in any layout of a `RecyclerView`'s list item, it repeats once in a while. In RecyclerViewAdapter's inner class `ViewHolder`, I set `onClickListener` of a layout called `mainLayout` in the list item. Clicking this should expand another layout called `expandableLayout` in the same list item. When clicked it not only expands the desired item, **but also every item once in 11 items**. Same goes for simple layout changes like changing text colors.

Here's the **RecyclerViewAdapter**:

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder>{

    private Context mContext;
    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    private DataManager mDataManager;

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager, Context context, ViewPager viewPager) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mViewPager = viewPager;
        this.mDataManager = new DataManager(mContext, mViewPager);
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
        FrameLayout mainLayout;
        RelativeLayout editButton;
        RelativeLayout deleteButton;
        ExpandableLayout expandableLayout;
        //Defined other View's of the item

        ViewHolder(View listItemLayout) {
            super(listItemLayout);

            this.mainLayout = listItemLayout.findViewById(R.id.listItem_mainLayout);
            this.editButton = listItemLayout.findViewById(R.id.expandedLogItem_edit);
            this.deleteButton = listItemLayout.findViewById(R.id.expandedLogItem_delete);
            this.expandableLayout = listItemLayout.findViewById(R.id.listItem_expandableLayout);

            this.mainLayout.setOnClickListener(this);
            this.editButton.setOnClickListener(this);
            this.deleteButton.setOnClickListener(this);

            //Initialized other View's of the item.
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (view.getId() == mainLayout.getId()) {
                expandableLayout.toggle();
                //This expands or collapses not just the clicked item,
                //but every item once in 11 items.
                //I tried other things like changing the text color 
                //of a TextView, and the result is the same.
            } else if (view.getId() == editButton.getId()) {
                mDataManager.editItemAt(getAdapterPosition());
            } else if (view.getId() == deleteButton.getId()) {
                mDataManager.deleteItemAt(getAdapterPosition());
                notifyItemRemoved(getAdapterPosition());
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        final View listItemLayout = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_list_item, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(listItemLayout);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
        //Populating other View's of the item.
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return logList.size();
    }
}
```

I am stuck on this problem for a while, and couldn't find or think of any method to solve this. Any respond would be appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you set the `onClickListener()` on a `View` from the item. Let's say you have a background image, and you will set the listener in `onBindViewHolder()` something like `holder.that_image_view.setOnClickListener()`

Comment: Actually I changed it to the current one in an attempt to solve the problem, because it didn't worked also.

Comment: You are right, with the answer of A. Kuckhinke, I moved listeners to the `onBindViewHolder()`, thank you.

Comment: So, after all it worked out this way? :D

Comment: Yeah, wouldn't take this long if I figured out in the first place. :D

Comment: Of course, it is always like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the name suggests, RecyclerView recycles ViewHolders when they are out of screen. So your `onBind` method is not always called with a freshly inflated ViewHolder, but maybe with one that has already been changed. For example, when scrolling down, Views that leave the screen on top are added at the bottom again.

Make sure to set all layout properties for the ViewHolder in `onBind`, for example whether the layout is expanded or not. You might have a boolean `isExpanded` in each item of your logList and set the expanded state according to that in `onBind`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, works like a charm. I'm suprised that I didn't think it that way.

Comment: Thank you! This was one of the weirdest errors I ever got, where it seemed like an if condition was totally ignored